# Find the volume of the solid which is restricted to the sphere $\rho=1$ and cones $\varphi=\pi/6$ and $\varphi=\pi/3$.

Tags: spherical-coordinates

Find the volume of the solid which is restricted to the sphere $\rho=1$ and cones $\varphi=\pi/6$ and  $\varphi=\pi/3$.

---

I always use a grapher to see how exactly the solid looks like,but in this case the surfaces are described in spherical coordinates and I don't know any program which plots them, so I need to convert them in Cartesian coordinates system,can someone help?

I know that $\rho^2=1=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and so we have a sphere of radius $1$, but what about the cones? How to convert them?

Comment: Why do you need the Cartesian coordinates? The volume is most simply (one line) to compute in the spherical ones. What does precisely $\varphi$ mean?

Comment: The point of using spherical coordinates is that it makes these objects easier to visualize. You cannot learn this if you rely on machines. It should be apparent that the answers given below will not help you find the volume.

Answer (score 1):

The volume bound between cones and sphere is straightforward in spherical coordinates. In this case for example, bounds of $\rho$ and $\theta$ are defined by the sphere. The lower and upper bounds of $\phi$ is defined by the cone. But if you had to convert this into cartesian coordinates, which is your question,

In spherical coordinates, $x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin \phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$.

$\sqrt {x^2+y^2} = \rho \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi, \tan \phi = \displaystyle  \frac {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z}$

For cone $ \ \phi = \frac{\pi}{6}$,
$\displaystyle \tan \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z}$

So the cone in cartesian coordinates is $z = \sqrt  {3 \ (x^2+y^2)}$

Find similarly for cone $\phi = \frac{\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a cone in spherical coordinates with the equation $\phi = \phi_0$.

From the definitions of our spherical coordinates we have $z = \rho \cos\phi$, and $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$, so $\phi = \arccos\left(\dfrac{z}{\rho}\right).$

Now we have $\arccos\left(\dfrac{z}{\rho}\right) = \phi_0,$ so converting everything to Cartesian we have $\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}=\cos(\phi_0).$
Now square both sides: $$\dfrac{z^2}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = \cos^2 (\phi_0) \to z^2 = \cos^2(\phi_0)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \to \sin^2(\phi_0) z^2 = \cos^2(\phi_0)(x^2 + y^2)$$.

Dividing both sides by $\sin^2(\phi_0)$ gives us $z^2 = \cot^2(\phi_0)(x^2 + y^2)$.

Comment: Cone $\phi = \phi_0$ defines a cone which opens either above $XY$ plane or below. Squaring it will define a cone which is both above and below the $XY$ plane. So you may want to add an appropriate condition $z \geq 0$ or $z \leq 0$ to the equation of the cone if you are writing as $z^2$.